# Using a JAR from a private Artifacts Feed in Data Factory Databricks task

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, databricks

My goal is to first publish JAR files of my Scala project to Azure DevOps Artifacts Feed and then use those JARs as part of my Databricks tasks in Azure Data Factory. I'm assuming I would have to use Maven as my library type and point the repository to the artefacts feed.

The feed is private and I haven't found a way to set up credentials for data factory to use it.

Is this possible in the first place? Could the credentials be embedded to the Maven Repository URL?

"Append libraries" options under Data Factory's Databricks task:

[image: "Append libraries" options under Data Factory's Databricks task]

Comment: private repositories aren't supported as of right now. But you can push your jar from CI/CD pipeline onto the DBFS (via databricks cli, for example), and then refer that jar from job configuration

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below commands? How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

Maven private repositories is not supported in Azure Databricks. If you want to install a private maven package, you can upload the package to DBFS and install the package via Databricks libraries CLI. See below example:

Upload to DBFS from local.

```
databricks fs cp "path/to/myPac.jar" dbfs:/mavenPrivate/jars
```

Install a JAR from DBFS

```
databricks libraries install --cluster-id $CLUSTER_ID --jar dbfs:/mavenPrivate/jars/myPac.jar
```